# Problem with MAC address getting changed to the original one upon connection

Tags: networking

I am making some tests with my router and it looks like the mac address I change by doing:

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 hw ether 01:02:03:04:05:06
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Gets changed to the original one when connecting to the rooter. I am on ubuntu

Comment: why not try using GUI ? if you mac is `23:B6:FD:3B:E7:35 (eth0)` as show in network manager change it to `01:02:03:04:05:06 (eth0)`. simple

Comment: No it has to be via conmand line. I am running securiry tests using the cli.

Comment: i suggest you to use fedora. you can change mac from GUI and it stays persistant. i used fedora once

Comment: The method I am showed you in answer is working for me even after several reboots and connect-disconnect. recently i have found an alternative, if you are interested let me know

Answer (score 0):

make this new script, this will make settings permanent !

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/if-up.d/changemac
```

paste this code, replace mac address you want

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$IFACE" = eth0 ]; then
ip link set dev "$IFACE" address 00:00:00:00:00:01
fi
```

`sudo chmod 755 /etc/network/if-up.d/changemac`

now disconnect the ethernet and connect again and check the mac by running `ifconfig`

---

(I know this may not be the proper solution, but as temporary measure)

you could try fedora. in fedora you change easily change mac address from GUI and it stays persistent.

Or wait for more responses

Comment: No chance! It's the ui that does what it wants. Whenever i connect to a network by clicking on the network item in the menu it flipping resets the mac. Even with the script u posted it does not work. Any other idea?

Comment: nope... i searched a lot